# how to select value From multi step List

Tags: javascript, angular, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I made a Multistep Drop Down Using UL and Li

code  :

```
            <li><a href="#">{{dropdowntext}}</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Exception on Leave</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Performance Reward</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Double Beat Working</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Working on Weekly-Off/Holiday</a></li>

                  </ul>
                </li>

              </ul>
            </li>

          </ul>
```

Please see  : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7cwuuw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

How do I take selected value from drop down using UL Li to the ts file .

I tried to do it using NgModule  bit It did not work . 
Please Look into this .

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a pure CSS solution for a drop-down, `NgModule` wouldn't work because the vanilla HTML elements do not have those directives. However, you could assign a common template reference variable to all the anchor tags and assign a common event handler to them. Try the following

Template

```html
<ul class="main-navigation">
  <li><a #option href="#">Select</a>
    <ul (select)="gg($event)" (change)="onChange($event)">
      <li><a #option href="#">Exception on Leave</a></li>
      <li><a #option href="#">Performance Reward</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a #option href="#">Double Beat Working</a></li>
          <li><a #option href="#">Working on Weekly-Off/Holiday</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Controller

```js
import { Component, ViewChildren, ElementRef, Renderer2, QueryList } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChildren('option', { read: ElementRef }) private options: QueryList<ElementRef>;
  private onMouseUp = (data) => { console.log(data); }

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  gg(evwent){
    alert("vdjv");
  }

  onChange(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.options.forEach(option => {
      this.renderer.listen(option.nativeElement, 'mouseup', () => {
        this.onMouseUp(option.nativeElement.innerHTML);
      });
    })
  }
}
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dgrmk6)